# Regex Match Not Happening - Unable To Identify The Reason

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a strange thing happening. For a regex

```
/"?\s*How.*Column\s?B$/sgm
```

applied on the input string that looks like:

```
"How to use this sheet
1. Each language selected by you in the survey settings is added as a tab in this sheet
2. You will see the questions categories and survey communications that need to be translated in Column B",,,,,,,,,,,,,
Post,Post Type,Sub Post Type,Post Translation,Option 1,Option 2,Option 3,Option 4,Option 5,Translated Option 1,Translated Option 2,Translated Option 3,Translated
```

The regex match does not happen. Why is it so? The string

- is starting with `"How`
- also has `Column B` in the third row

Here is also the [regex101 test I created](https://regex101.com/r/lKQAvT/1) and the screenshot below for better clarity

[image]

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: `B` is not at the end of line. Remove `$` or replace with `"`

Comment: In terms of regex, `$` is the terminal match.